# What is the location on this 16th century baptism record?

Tags: england, palaeography, 16th-century

Randle Case was baptised in the parish of St Oswald, Chester, in May 1589. His father was Thomas Case and the record seems to read "Randle Case, sonne of Thomas Case of ----", but I can't figure out this last bit.

Any suggestions? I think it could be Flookersbrook, a part of modern day Hoole Village, but I'm not sure and would like confirmation.

[image: Baptism record of Randle Case]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fluker's Brooke, which is now Flookersbrook in Hoole.

http://chester.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Flookersbrook

Answer (score 0):

Looking into Hoole Village there is mention of Mickle Trafford and District. I wonder if it is Trafford spelled Traford. It is not uncommon for words in the late 1500's to be spelled differently from today.

Comment: Don't think it says trafford to be honest; think its Fluker's Brooke